# how to use inner future value in outer future in scala

Tags: scala, future

Hi I have two Futures FutureA and FutureB i want to take a value from FutureB and use it in FutureA but all i am getting is null 
here is code

```
futureA = ask(ActorA, MessageA).mapTo[Int]
  FutureB = ask(ActorB, MessageB).mapTo[Int]
  var someResult=0

      futureA.map {
        result =>
             FutureB.map { x => 
                someResult=x//suppose it will retun 5
             }
             someResult=someResult+1//it should give 6
             println(someResult)//here i am getting 1
      }
```

I want `someResult` to return `6` but it is returning `1` 
how can I achieve that 
I do not want to use blocking call `await.result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dima's answer is absolutely correct. You're not assigning the result of `FutureB.map` so it's basically a side effect potentially executed in a background thread without your code knowing. You're likely to reach the print statement at runtime before the variable gets incremented, but maybe not, you can't know.

The right way of doing it is to use immutable variables and to chain your futures using flatMap/map.

Say you have a function called `someFunction` that takes two `Int`s and return a `Result` type : `def someFunction(a: Int, b: Int): Result`. You can then write the following code:

```
val result: Future[Result] =
  futureA.flatMap { a =>
    FutureB.map { b =>
      someFunction(a, b)
    }
  }
```

You can also write it using a for-comprehension which compile to exactly the same thing but is the standard way of doing it:

```
val result: Future[Result] =
  for {
    a <- futureA
    b <- FutureB
  } yield someFunction(a, b)
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `var`, especially with futures. That's code smell and asking for trouble.

```
  futureA
    .flatMap { _ => FutureB }
    .map { _ + 1 }
    .onSuccess(println)
```

Comment: but i want to take the value from FutureB and use in futureA how would i do that